# Avoda Zara - Star & Crescent

Tags: avodah-zarah, islam

Are there any sources on restrictions on objects adorned with the Islamic star and crescent like there are the Christian cross? I'm aware that whether Islam is Avoda Zara is debated, but I'm not familiar with any discussion specific to the star and crescent under either context.

If one is to assume that Islam is Avoda Zara, then would the same restrictions as the cross apply? If it it isn't Avoda Zara, then are there any restrictions to it (and possibly other Islamic symbols) that still apply?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: From Wikipedia-Unlike the cross, which is a symbol of Jesus' crucifixion in Christianity, there is no solid link that connects the star and crescent symbol with the concept of Islam. The connotation is widely believed to have come from the flag of Ottoman Empire, whose prestige as an Islamic empire and caliphate led to the adoption of its state emblem as a symbol of Islam by association. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_and_crescent